# How to make sentry auto detect error/crash in android

Tags: android, kotlin, sentry

Is it possible to send errors/crash reports automatically on android in every activity
Or is it completely manual and should i use the manifest configuration or sentry.properties, Sorry i am new to Sentry, i have used manual error capturing but is automatic possible

Existing code for manual error handling

AndroidManifest.xml configuration

```xml
<meta-data android:name="io.sentry.dsn" android:value="dsn" />
```

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
Sentry.init("dsn", AndroidSentryClientFactory(this.applicationContext))
       try {
            Log.d("sentrytest1","try")
             throw Exception("This is a test.")

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("sentrytest1","catch")
            Sentry.capture(e)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Sentry Android SDK](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-android) will capture exceptions automatically if they are not handled by your code (through a `catch` block). That includes crashes from native libraries (C/C++) that you might use directly or indirectly via JNI. These are crashes.

That said, if you're handling the error, and would like the app to continue running, but you would like to send this error to Sentry so you can be aware/investigate it, you can do that with `Sentry.captureException(e)`;

I noticed in your example that you're mixing the initialization of the Sentry Android SDK version 1 and 2.

The Sentry Android v2 initializes itself automatically, all you need to do is to set the `dsn` in the manifest as you did in your example. There's no need to call `Sentry.init` unless you'd like to customize a few things (like a `beforeSend` callback).

You can find this information and more on the [SDK documentation](http://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/).

Comment: Whst version of the sdk are you using? On your gradle file, io.sentry.android 2.2.x?

Comment: io.sentry:sentry-android:1.7.30 from gradle

Comment: Can you please upgrade to the latest version. The answer talks about version 1 vs 2

Comment: FYI, can not make it run out-of-the-box - test exception doesn't come to Sentry console. Not sure it configures itself automatically.